# Does Botium box requires docker container to be killed on every system start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've read the command for `docker kill`. Now exactly how to stop
all containers or kill the container?

Should I navigate to the Docker folder in program files in cmd, or should I navigate to botium folder which I created for botium box in cmd? Currently I have Docker desktop version.

I'm getting the below error:

- I restarted the Docker desktop app
- Cmd : navigated to botium folder which I created for botium box
- entered : `docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up`

**Error was thrown**

> C:\Users\Ram\Documents\Botium>docker-compose -f
>   docker-compose-all.yml up Starting botium_redis_1 ... botium_mysql_1
>   is up-to-date Starting botium_prisma_1 ... error
>
> ERROR: for botium_prisma_1  Cannot start service prisma: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint botStarting
>   botium_redis_1  ... error lready allocated
>
> ERROR: for botium_redis_1  Cannot start service redis: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint botium_redis_1
>   (023c3f7d0101a509a677a2f5434b00f25a8e4d3e238166eae6e0c1678b81035b):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:6379 failed: port is already allocated
>
> ERROR: for prisma  Cannot start service prisma: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint botium_prisma_1
>   (1ad423ca349cd5d987a082407c64c8300e2822a0e4c3bf6a63c4369705f1413a):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:4466 failed: port is already allocated
>
> ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint botium_redis_1
>   (023c3f7d0101a509a677a2f5434b00f25a8e4d3e238166eae6e0c1678b81035b):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:6379 failed: port is already allocated ERROR:
>   Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

However when I retried the http://127.0.0.1:4000/quickstart a couple of times
the botium box opened. But initially this was not opening.

Comment: You don't need to navigate anywhere. Docker command sees your containers from everywhere.

Comment: Can u give me sample syntax to kill or stop docker container

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to navigate.

If you run using docker-compose, you can go to the directory where your `docker-compose.yml` file is located and run `docker-compose down`.

Without docker-compose, you have to run `docker ps` to list all currently running containers and find the name of the container to kill. You can use the CONTAINER ID or the NAMES. Then run `docker kill <container name>`.

Example:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
myId                myimage:2.5                       "/opt/command/ba…"        24 hours ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp             very_cool_name_1
$ docker kill very_cool_name_1
very_cool_name_1
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type below commands when you open your Powershell or Bash.

To stop all running containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

To remove all containers:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
```

Please note that rm will just remove your container not the Docker image. If your want to delete an image then you can use: docker rmi -f container_id

Comment: Bash ? did you mean Git CLI